# What is the world generator mod used in the Tekkit big dig pack?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods, minecraft-tekkit

I was wondering what the world generator for the Tekkit Big Dig pack is, as I would like to install this into the tekkit pack (if anyone knows how to install custom mods in tekkit, please let me know). Also, do big dig and tekkit use the same "ore mods", so I can just simply  generate a world in big dig, and transfer it to tekkit?

Comment: Which part of world generation are you talking about: ores, landscape shape, biomes, …?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This used to be the [Metallurgy](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/744918-146132forgebukkitsmp-metallurgy-2-242-putting-the-mine-back-in-minecraft/) mod-pack originally (so may be of use to you if you are wanting to use it separately for this purpose)

Taken from the big dig [changelogs](http://www.technicpack.net/big-dig) for v 1.3.2

> Removed Metallurgy (taken over by CoFH Core)

It was taken out and replaced instead by [CoFH Core](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1297506-151-thermal-expansion-230b7-updates-and-refactors-ahoy/) (part of Thermal Expansion), the makers of which can be found on this thread.

As a side note, big dig and the current version of tekkit use very different mods, i can't guarantee that you can just copy a map across without causing issues. Though i will test this when i get home and update this post accordingly

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Big Dig *started* with Metallurgy, but it's not in [the Big Dig mod list](http://www.technicpack.net/big-dig) anymore.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie oops, correct, though i have found its replacement. nicely spotted

Comment: Oh good! 'Cause I haven't been able to figure it out just by looking at mod lists.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie did some recon, poked change logs for Big Dig and found its replacement. "Version 1.3.2:  Removed Metallurgy (taken over by CoFH Core)"

Comment: Nice detective work.